# How to convert list of JsonObject from google json to JsonNode object of Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I have a list of `JsonObject` which is from google JSON library and then I need to call a third party library which accepts a `JsonNode` object from the Jackson library.

I don't have much experience with JSON and have been reading about these and from [this](http://Abstract%20class,%20used%20when%20reading%20a%20JSON%20document.) link knows that `JsonNode` is a abstract class, hence can't create it and looks like I have to use `ObjectNode` for storing/converting the `JsonObject` **but looks like it would require some parse to do that.**

**Could somebody please help me convert the `JsonObject` to `ObjectNode` ?**

Comment: stringify from source and then convert to target type

Comment: @Kris, I tried stringify the `jsonobject` using `toString` but don't know after that how to convert it `ObjectNode`, ie can you give some code sample for 2nd part

Comment: Well I think its just a matter of google search, which will give results like these https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-to-jsonnode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could somebody please help me convert the `JsonObject` to `ObjectNode`?

It could be achieved with the following code:

```java
private JsonNode toJsonNode(JsonObject jsonObject) throws IOException {
    return mapper.readTree(jsonObject.toString());
}
```

To convert back, you may use:

```java
private JsonObject toJsonObject(JsonNode jsonNode) throws IOException {
    String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    return jsonParser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
}
```

---

Depending on your needs, for a more generic solution, you may consider using `JsonElement` rather than `JsonObject`. The code is very similar to the code shown above:

```java
private JsonNode toJsonNode(JsonElement jsonElement) throws IOException {
    return mapper.readTree(jsonElement.toString());
}
```

```java
private JsonElement toJsonElement(JsonNode jsonNode) throws IOException {
    String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    return jsonParser.parse(jsonString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the performance/elegance point of view, the stringify strategy is not very nice because you're doing a lot of useless work.

Instead, you could use `dev.voigon:gson-jackson-interop` (see https://github.com/liorsl/gson-jackson-interop) that transforms Jackson tree objects into Gson tree objects.

Use it like that :

```java
        JsonElement gsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(myObject);
        JsonNode jacksonNode = NodeConverter.gsonToJackson(gsonElement);
```